# ¿Cómo se puede obtener un identificador único del cpu?

Tags: java

Estoy creando una aplicación de escritorio en Java que pretendo comercializar (al menos para pagar los costes del desarrollo). He pensado en implementar un sistema de licencias que se base en clave pública y clave privada. Mi idea es que la aplicación genere un código en base al hardware del pc en el que corre, que el cliente me mande ese código y yo le devuelva el código firmado con mi clave privada y el lo introduzca en la aplicación la cual sabrá descifrarlo con la clave pública.

Esto es lo que quiero conseguir, pero quiero saber si esto es posible y cómo:
¿Puedo en Java obtener un identificador de la CPU? Sé que puede obtenerse la mac de los dispositivos de red pero también sé que puede que tengan más de uno con lo cual tal vez le genero una licencia asociada a un dispositivo que no caracteriza al pc, por ejemplo, un dispositivo usb, o una vpn.

Entiendo que lo ideal sería una combinación de mac y cpu.

Por el caso de uso de la aplicación lo normal es que los pcs que corran esta aplicación sean portátiles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Con esto puedes obtener el serial de tu placa madre en windows, si necesitas en otras arquitecturas tendrás que adaptar el script.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class MiscUtils {
  private MiscUtils() {  }

  public static String getMotherboardSN() {
  String result = "";
    try {
      File file = File.createTempFile("realhowto",".vbs");
      file.deleteOnExit();
      FileWriter fw = new java.io.FileWriter(file);

      String vbs =
         "Set objWMIService = GetObject(\"winmgmts:\\\\.\\root\\cimv2\")\n"
        + "Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _ \n"
        + "   (\"Select * from Win32_BaseBoard\") \n"
        + "For Each objItem in colItems \n"
        + "    Wscript.Echo objItem.SerialNumber \n"
        + "    exit for  ' do the first cpu only! \n"
        + "Next \n";

      fw.write(vbs);
      fw.close();
      Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cscript //NoLogo " + file.getPath());
      BufferedReader input =
        new BufferedReader
          (new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
      String line;
      while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
         result += line;
      }
      input.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result.trim();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    String cpuId = MiscUtils.getMotherboardSN();
    javax.swing.JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog((java.awt.Component)
         null, cpuId, "Motherboard serial number",
         javax.swing.JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);
  }
}
```

Fuente: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0580.html

Pd: También te muestra cómo obtener el s/n del disco, entre otros.

Comment: Hola Alexis, al ir a poner en practica el método que comentas obtengo el siguiente resultado: To be filled by the O.E.M. Lo ejecuto en una placa gigabyte.